# Typedef in header file with variable from a source file

Tags: c++

I have a header file in where I store various typedefs. The problem is that I need to pass a variable from a source file to one of those typedefs.

I have tried this:

```
extern const unsigned int number;
typedef Storage<double,number> store;
```

in the header file.

Then in the source file, the *number* variable is instantiated at execution time:

```
const unsigned int number( conf->ReadNumber() );
```

However, it does not work.

Is this thing possible? Any idea?

Comment: Is that a function call ? Did you meant `const unsigned int number = conf -> ReadNumber() ;` ? Please post the exact error message.

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't misspell "typedef" as "typefed" in the real code like you did in this post... did you?

Comment: Depends where the `const` is located. I presume it's global from looking at the `extern`. Inside a function it would work, globally it would only work for stuff that exists at compile-time (not for functions that have to be called).

Comment: It is not possible. But take a look at templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Storage<double,number>` wait for `number` to be a constant expression : It's value must be computable at compile time.